# array of check boxes using html and php

Tags: php, html, arrays, checkbox

I have a chunk of code that is as follows:

```
<td><?
    $days = array("Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thur","Fri","Sat");
    for($i=1;$i<8;$i++)
    {
        echo $days[$i-1]?><input type="checkbox" name="labDays[]" value="<?=$days[$i]?>" checked="checked"><?
    }?>
</td>
```

However when I run `print_r($_REQUEST['labDays']);`

I get `Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => [3] => [4] => [5] => [6] => )`

I expected `Array ( [0] => Sun[1] => Mon[2] => Tue[3] => Wed[4] => Thur[5] => Fri[6] => Sat)`

I'm sure it's something silly but I'm not sure what I am missing...

`print_r($_REQUEST)` pukes: `Array ( [pg] => 12 [msg] => Facility Already Exist [facilityname] => kjgkjhgkjhg [facorgtype] => [facilitytype] => [administratorsname] => [divisionname] => [streetaddress1] => [streetaddress2] => [city] => [state] => [zipcode] => [phonenumber] => [faxnumber] => [email] => [mainstate] => [labDays] => Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => [3] => [4] => [5] => [6] => ) [facBillingContact] => [facBillingPhone] => [facBillingFax] => [facBillingRep] => [facBillingAccNum] => [facNotes] => [submit] => Create )`

`var_dump($_REQUEST['labDays'])`:

```
array
  0 => string 'Sun' (length=3)
  1 => string 'Mon' (length=3)
  2 => string 'Tue' (length=3)
  3 => string 'Wed' (length=3)
  4 => string 'Thur' (length=4)
  5 => string 'Fri' (length=3)
  6 => string 'Sat' (length=3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
    <?php
    $days = array("Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat");
    foreach ($days as $day) {
        echo <<<HTML
    <label>$day
        <input type="checkbox" name="labDays[]" value="$day" checked>
    </label>
HTML;

    }
    ?>
```

Few notes:

**PHP**

- The use of the shorthand syntax (`<? ?>` and especially `<?= ?>`) is not recommended.
- For iterating an array, `foreach` is more suited than a `for`.
- I use PHP's heredoc syntax for strings. This way I avoid the quotes confusion.
- Use `$_POST` or `$_GET` rather than `$_REQUEST`, it's considered more secure that way.

**HTML**

- Use labels for form elements in HTML, this associates the text with the form control, plus when you click on the text, it will mark the appropriate checkbox too!
- The `checked` attribute needs no value. It's enough that it's there.

Comment: what is `echo <<<HTML`?! i have never seen this before

Comment: @Truth, so for every single HTML tag looping you write heredoc?

Comment: @Truth, OP is already confused, you are confusing him more :)

Comment: @Bill.Caffery: I see the intended result. Check the result of the entire `$_POST` variable (not just what you think you should see).

Comment: @KalpeshMehta: I'm not confusing him, I'm pointing him at the right direction, with good programming practices. Heredoc is far superior to all other forms of strings when writing HTML **blocks** (not one-liners) because it's easily visible, evaluates variables while not messing with quotes. So yes, I will use it for every single HTML tag I'm looping. In more complex cases, I would even use DOM.

Comment: @Bill.Caffery: Also: see **[heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)**.

Comment: @Bill.Caffery: If this answer solved your problem, consider upvoting and accepting it, by clicking on the large green tick mark under the answer's score.

Comment: @Truth sorry i was so excited/embarrassed i forgot but ty

Answer (score 1):

If you want to loop through array, `foreach` is best option

```
$days = array("Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thur","Fri","Sat");
foreach($days as $k=>$v)
{
    echo $k?><input type="checkbox" name="labDays[]" value="<?=$v?>" checked="checked"><?
}?>
```

Using `for`, you can do like this:

```
$days = array("Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thur","Fri","Sat");
for($i=0;$i<=6;$i++)
{
    echo $i;?><input type="checkbox" name="labDays[]" value="<?=$days[$i]?>" checked="checked"><?
}?>
```

RECOMMENDED WAY..

```
$days = array("Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thur","Fri","Sat");
foreach($days as $k=>$v)
{
    echo $k . ' <input type="checkbox" name="labDays[]" value="'.$v.'" checked="checked">'; //you can give your styles and css ofcourse to make it better..
}
```

Comment: This sort of syntax is not recommended.

Comment: @Truth, yes I know, just letting the OP find the mistake.

Comment: i dont want it to say 1[] 2[] 3[] i want mon[] tue[] wed[]. but i see the concatenation you did with `.$v.` so ty i will try that

Comment: if you want like: mon [checkbox], tue [checkbox], just replace $k with $v that's it..

Comment: can you check the html source and confirm if the `value` field is getting correct values? (mon, sun, etc..)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe with *echo* to print the value:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="labDays[]" value="<?php echo $days[$i]; ?>" checked="checked">
```

Comment: This makes no difference. He uses the shorthand syntax `<?= $stuff ?>` which is equivalent to `<?php echo $stuff; ?>`.

Comment: Yes but it requires to be configured in php.ini: http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag

Comment: `Since PHP 5.4.0, <?= is always available.` from the same source you've linked.

Comment: I'm not side by side with Bill, I don't know which version he is using. Maybe is written somewhere but I didn't see it. Or he is using an old php.ini configuration ... how can I know?

Comment: ive enable short tags enough squabbling ty